# Does ethers.js automatically calculate gas costs?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, fees

```
const contractAddress = "Contract Address";
const ABI = "ABI data JSON"

const Web3 = require("web3");
 const transaction = {
    'from' :account.address, 
    'gas': 95000,
    'gasPrice' : web3.utils.toWei("35", "gwei"),
 };
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,contractAddress)
let result = await contract.methods.mint(to,amount).send(transaction); // require transaction data
```

In the case of the **web3JS module**, when calling a smart contract function, the gas fee must be written in the transaction data.

```
const contractAddress = "Contract Address";
const ABI = "ABI data JSON"

const { ethers,Contract } = require("ethers");
const contract = new Contract(contractAddress,ABI,signer);
let result = await contract.connect(signer).mint(to,amount); // no transaction data
```

When using the **ethersJS module**, the transaction is sent by predicting the gas fee without specifying the gas fee to be used.

**Does EthersJS automatically estimate and calculate gas costs?**

+When sending a transaction with EthersJS, how do I write the code to directly enter the gas fee like web3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EthersJS, when estimating the required amount of gas for a transaction, a node is queried for its best guess. If a node is unable (or unwilling) to predict the cost, the `UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT` error occurs.

See: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/logger/#errors--unpredicatable-gas-limit

You can follow the example below to write the code to directly enter the gas fee like web3 when sending a transaction with EthersJS.

```
const url = `provider url`
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url)
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privKey, provider)

const tx = await wallet.sendTransaction({
       to: account,
       value: 90000000000,
       gasPrice: 250000000000,
       gasLimit: 21000,
   })

const receipt = await tx.wait()
```

See: https://medium.com/klaytn/using-ethereum-tools-in-klaytn-dc068d48de04